# Rails Guardfile Won't Watch Concerns Dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, guard

My Guardfile mostly works except that I can't get it to watch a concerns dir. The problem must be with my regexp which I've written below.

My concerns dir is built like this :

```
/app/models/concerns/dir_for_concerns/some_concern.rb
```

And the specs dirs is what you'd expect:

```
 /spec/models/concerns/dir_for_concerns/some_concern.rb
```

Guardfile.rb

```
 watch(%r{^app/models/concerns/(\w)+/(\w)+\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/models/concerns/#{m[1]}/#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
```

Comment: Is your description accurate? `Guardfile` shouldn't have `.rb` and your spec file is missing `_spec`, which your regex is trying to match.

Comment: Try `watch(%r{^app/models/concerns/(\w+)/(\w+)\.rb\z})`. You misplaced the capturing groups, and in RoR you need to use `\z` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good idea to support out of the box, so I created an issue here: https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/issues/366

(You can comment/vote on it to encourage someone to implement it sooner).

I'd probably handle it with something simple like this:

```
watch(%r{^app/(models/concerns/.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
```